# how to solve unmounted component warning in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've successfully developed my first React Native application, but having a lot of warning message. Among them, and mostly common i'm getting this warning message.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

 in ToastContainer (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(ToastContainer) (at Root.js:16)
    in RCTView (at Root.js:14)
    in Root (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Root) (at OneTimePasswordScreen.js:149)
```

But I have no idea where to look at to solve this error. I looked at the source map and noticed `OneTimePasswordScreen.js:149` this line. When i log into that line, it is the root of my component which leads/point to nothing (at least i can't understand). Can anyone point me out where i should look at to solve those errors Or is there any kind of debug tool which will indicate those unmounted components!

Note: I don't want to ignore this warning. So looking for a solution to solve them!

Here is one of my component code:

```
//packages
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Root } from 'native-base';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

//assets and components
import bgHeader from './../header.png';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            isLoading: false
        }
    }
    clipPage() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AllCustomer');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Root style={styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={ bgHeader }
                    style={styles.imageHeader}
                    resizeMode='stretch'>

                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 30 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.dashboardText}>DASHBOARD</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.wrapperView}>
                        <View style={styles.dashboardView}>
                            <Button light style={styles.dashboardCategory} onPress={this.clipPage.bind(this)}>
                                <Icon style={styles.iconStyle} name="users" size={30} />
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Clip </Text>
                            </Button>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            </Root>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    imageHeader: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: 110
    },
    dashboardText: {
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    wrapperView: {
        marginTop: 100,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    dashboardView: {
        width: '80%',
    },
    dashboardCategory: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 140,
        borderRadius: 5,
        elevation: 5,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    iconStyle: {
        color: 'grey',
        fontSize: 35
    },
    buttonText: {
        marginTop: 10,
        color: '#4b2e80',
        width: '100%',
        textAlign:'center',
        fontSize: 20
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shown warning's usually show up when this.setState() is called in a component even though the component got already unmounted. Please go through [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component) and check your all components.

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thats a good point,, i will look into my states and see if i did something like that..

Comment: you are right, That was the case, i was updating some state while changing the component..